# Мне надо сделать playlist в console

Tags: java, kotlin

В приложении должно быть меню (а)

1. Воспроизвести музыку
2. Изменить музыку
3. Воспроизвести музыку

Если Player вводит 1. (Play Music) должно появиться другое меню, например:

- 1. Художники
     Должен появиться список художников, чтобы ввести одного из художников
     После выбора исполнителя должно появиться меню
- 1 (1). Альбомы:В меню альбома должны открываться песни этого исполнителя в текущем альбоме | пользователь может выбрать
  песня
- 1 (2). Песни:Песни должны открывать все песни этого исполнителя | Пользователь может выбрать песню (см. 2. Песни *)
- 2. Песни
     должны появиться все песни, или запросить поиск песни | пользователь может ввести ключевое слово для поиска или
     войдите в один из них
- 3. Альбомы
     должны появиться все альбомы или спросить поиск по альбомам | пользователь может ввести ключевое слово для поиска или
     войдите в один из них
     если пользователь войдет в один из альбомов, откроет все песни этого альбома и будет работать как
     (см. 2. Песни *)
- 4. Жанры
     должны появиться все жанры | пользователь может войти в один из жанров
     если пользователь входит в один из жанров, должны открываться все альбомы этого жанра.
     (см. 3. Альбомы **)

2. Изменить музыку

Если Player вводит 2. (Изменить музыку) должно появиться другое меню, например:

1. Добавьте музыку
   спросит пользователя художника
   после выбора исполнителя необходимо запросить альбомы пользователей
   после выбора альбома необходимо попросить пользователя ввести название песни (не должно позволять добавлять
   пусто) и добавить в текущий альбом (текущая информация)
2. Удалить музыку
   спросит пользователя художника
   после выбора исполнителя необходимо запросить альбомы пользователей
   после выбора альбома должен появиться список песен и спросить, какую песню хотите удалить.
   И после выбора песни
   Песня класса должна содержать информацию об альбоме, информацию об исполнителе, длину песни, название, жанр.

Исполнитель класса должен содержать список альбомов, название и жанр.
Классный альбом должен содержать список песен, название, год выпуска и исполнителя.
Жанр - перечисление.

- Функция воспроизведения нот ()
  ** Примечание. Альбом и исполнитель должны иметь функцию playAll(), которая будет воспроизводить все песни.
  в нем (альбом всех песен или всех песен исполнителя).

Comment: Что пробовал? Что не получилось? Что не понятно? Делать за тебя никто не будет.

Comment: Мдээ, сейчас сделаем, конечно, тут ведь все по совместительству фрилансеры на добровольной основе :)
Если ты пытался и не получилось, скинь сюда свой код и ошибку, на которую наткнулся.